# How I can make a custom vertical slider in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I'm learning C#, and I'm making a WPF Application.

The trouble is:

I have tried, but I don't know how to make a simple image object be a slider.

I have an idea to get values, calculating by the position of image object. I only need help to move the object image by the mouse.

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean by drag and drop operations or mouse move operations?

Comment: I want to know how to move the image in runtime, as a slider.

Comment: Do you have an image of what your desired output is?

Comment: I want to get that result: http://s27.postimg.org/411jo776b/send.png

Comment: Does the link provided by the moderators provide you with your answer?

Comment: I caught several stretches codes in questions on this site and managed to make my slider!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the answer that you wanted, but it is *the* answer. You need to declare a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `Slider` control. This is no task for a new developer really, but there is some help at hand. First, I recommend that you read through the [WPF Control Templates - An Overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jitghosh/archive/2007/12/27/wpf-control-templates-an-overview.aspx) page on MSDN for some background to this task.

Next, if you're not put off by that read, you can find the default `ControlTemplate` for the `Slider` in the [Slider Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. It's always best to start with the default `ControlTemplate` and to get that working before you make any changes to it. From there, you should just make small changes and run your project regularly to ensure that your changes are what you wanted. You'll get there in the end.